# View the role assigned to each user (Report Server)

Tags: permissions, ssrs, scripting, automation

Is there anyway I could list down the roles assigned to each user on the different folders on ReportServer Database and in that SQL statement I should be able to declare something like
    `@User_Name` of the reporting user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found My Answer from a Blog Almost similar :) !!!

```
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(200) = 'UserName' 

SELECT Rol.RoleName,Us.UserName ,Cat.PATH,Cat.[Name] ReportName,
CASE Cat.Type WHEN 1 THEN 'Folder' WHEN 2 THEN 'Report' 
WHEN 3 THEN 'Resource' WHEN 4 THEN 'Linked Report' 
WHEN 3 THEN 'Data Source' ELSE '' END AS CatalogType
,Cat.Description 
FROM Catalog Cat     --Parent
INNER JOIN Policies Pol 
ON Cat.PolicyID = Pol.PolicyID
INNER JOIN PolicyUserRole PUR 
ON Pol.PolicyID = PUR.PolicyID 
INNER JOIN Users Us 
ON PUR.UserID = Us.UserID 
INNER JOIN Roles Rol 
ON PUR.RoleID = Rol.RoleID
WHERE   Cat.Type in (1,2)
AND  ( Us.UserName LIKE @UserName  )
ORDER BY Cat.PATH
```